# paypal api access page not display fully

Tags: paypal

I have issue with paypal when request api access.

I have click on selling tools -> API access -> update. Then it redirect to the page https://www.paypal.com/businessmanage/credentials/apiAccess.

After the page fully loaded. It don't display the text below the **Learn more** link. So I can't process more.

I have changed to different computers, phones, internet connections, browsers but it not solved the problem. I have created another account but it still meet that issue and I don't know why some my friends have used Paypal but don't have this issue. And they still can't solve my situation.

So please help me!

[Paypal access API page not display fully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGLA2.png)

Comment: Please file an MTS ticket at https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/ PayPal support portal, then MTS team will check this issue further.

Comment: Thank PP_Punna. I have sent them ticket. I check it today and the problem has been solved even they haven't responded yet. Thank you!

Comment: Gald to hear that your issue has been resolved.